# Assign network adapter dedicated to VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox

My host system is running Xubuntu 14.04 and I'm having the network interfaces eth1 and wlan0. Both are connected to different networks, which under no circumstances shall be connected to each other. In addition I'm using VirtualBox running a Windows VM.

Is there a save way to connect one of the network adapters (if available) dedicated to the VM (if running)? For example having wlan0 always connected to the host, but eth1 always to the guest? But even if the guest is not running eth1 should never be available to the host.